# Prove that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S$, defined by $f(x)=s_x$ is continuous

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Let $S\subset \mathbb{R}$ a closed set such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ exists an only $s_x\in S$ such that $d(x,s_x)=d(x,S)$. Prove that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S$, defined by $f(x)=s_x$ is continuous.

Well, i tried to see the continuity of $f$ by taking a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, so i can see this: $x_n\rightarrow x \iff f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$, but i'm stuck here. Any suggestion?

Comment: What is $s_x$ in this instance?

Comment: an element of $S$

Comment: I not sure what you mean by "exists an only $s_x \in S$. Do you mean that this $s_x$ is uniqe for each $x$?

Comment: yes, i think so.

Answer (score 2):

If $S=\mathbb{R}$, it is easy prove the property. Suppose that $U={}^c S$ is not empty, then this open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is equal to the union of it connected components, these components are disjoint open intervals. Suppose that there is among these intervals an $]a,b[$ with $a, b\in \mathbb{R}$, $a<b$. We have $a,b\in S$. Then for $\displaystyle c=\frac{a+b}{2}$, we have $d(c,S)=d(c,a)=d(c,b)$, in contradiction with the hypothesis. Hence $U$ is $]u,+\infty[$, $]-\infty,v[$, or the union  $]-\infty,v[\cup ]u,+\infty[$, with $v<u$. So $S$ is $]-\infty, u]$, or $[v,+\infty[$, or $[v,u]$. It is now easy to find $f(x)$, and to finish.

Comment: So it is true on $\mathbb R$.  Probably that is what the question intends.  Now: what about other metric spaces?  If the "nearest point in $S$" is unique, then must it be continuous?